# Telegram API Groups

Tags: telegram

Is it possible to create and maintain groups when creating your own custom client app utilizing the telegram API?

Looking at the documentation, https://core.telegram.org/methods, there is no API listed for groups (or is there more recent documentation kept elsewhere), although the Android Client for Telegram provides the functionality to create groups of up to 5000 members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [messages.createChat](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.createChat) method for that.